# wildcard subdomains and subsubdomains configuration in apache

Tags: apache-2.2

I would like to have two virtualhosts:

1) one of them with

```
ServerName mydomain.com
ServerAlias *.mydomain.com
```

2) other with

```
ServerName beta.mydomain.com
ServerAlias *.beta.mydomain.com 
(or if it's easier, it could be beta.*.mydomain.com)
```

How can i do it?

I've tried loading one first and then another (and viceversa) but it's not working.

Thanx !

Comment: Dare I ask... why?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are missing the `NameVirtualHost` directive:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName beta.example.com
        ServerAlias *.beta.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/b
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias *.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/a
</VirtualHost>
```

The `NameVirtualHost` directive that tells apache that the `VirtualHost`s matching the address:port given are supposed to be name-based (using the client's `Host:` header) rather than based on the address:port alone.  With this, the beta virtual host *has* to be first since apache will use the first matching VirtualHost directive, and *.example.com will match beta.example.com.

Comment: No, I'm not missing it :P

Comment: @user75317 The block I pasted worked for me.  Update your question with what's going wrong (error messages? always serving one vhost? Which vhost? What's your actual vhost configuration?)

Comment: I pasted your config (changing example for my domain), and all points to the /var/www/a ... it's like the second virtualhost overrides the first one. I'm using Server version: Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Nov 18 2010 21:17:29